# net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver not found by lucee.core

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I want to generate jasper pdf on my lucee server but i have issue with my jar lib on lucee.

I have try on with the same code and the same file on coldfusion11.

```
class = CreateObject("java", "java.lang.Class");
class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
driverManager = CreateObject("java", "java.sql.DriverManager");
option = 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433;DatabaseName=XXX;user=XX;Password=XXXX';
connection = driverManager.getConnection(option);
```

when i use on lucee i got message 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver not found by lucee.core [64]'.
i have search if my jar is not detected.
But if i search on my lucee admin i can see my jar on the list of jars that apply into application.
it says :

Bundle-Version-File name-Vendor-Used by-State

jTDS JDBC Driver (jtds.1.3.1)-0.0.0.0-jtds-1.3.1.jar- - -active

as i can see the jar is already detected.

I can go through by not using java.lang.Class like this :

```
class = CreateObject("java", "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").init();
driverManager = CreateObject("java", "java.sql.DriverManager");
option = 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433;DatabaseName=xxx;user=xx;Password=xxxx';
connection = driverManager.getConnection(option);
```

but if using this i got another error 
'No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433...'

anyone know what cause this?

Answer (score 0):

try putting them in the lib folder right under your project, then add into build path. and one more this

correct you DB URL `'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433;DatabaseName=XXX;user=XX;Password=XXXX';`. you can use link:

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

So, to connect to a database called "xxx" hosted by a MS SQL Server running on 192.168.99.112, you may end up with something like this:

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433/xxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS;user=xx;password=xxxx
Or, if you prefer to use getConnection(url, "xx", "xxxx"):

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.99.112:1433/xxx;instance=SQLEXPRESS

Comment: i already try this, but not have any diff with the code before. the jar is already in the correct place.the jar is detected but it cannot be accessed by the java to connect db.

Comment: try to ping your server with port, you can use this command : `telnet 192.168.99.112 1433`